# reason why the series does not converge

Tags: analysis

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-nx}$$
Why do we conclude that the series does not converge,if $x \leq 0$ ?

Because of the fact that $f_n(x)=e^{-nx} \to +\infty, \text{ if }x \leq 0  $ ?

Comment: It doesn't converge to $+\infty$ for $x = 0$. But that $e^{-nx}$ does not converge to $0$ for $x \leqslant 0$ is sufficient to conclude divergence.

Comment: @DanielFischer do you mean it doesn't converge to $+\infty$ for $x\gt 0$?

Comment: @ellya I meant $f_n(x) = e^{-nx}$ with "It", not the series.

Comment: ohh.. yes that is true..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a series $\sum u_n $converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = 0$. This is a basic result that you seem to be familiar with already.

Now if $x = 0$, then the limit in question is $1$. If $x < 0$, the limit is $\infty$. Therefore the series doesn't converge when $x \le 0$.

Comment: Ok,I understand...And what happens,if $x>0$ ? Why is it then $0< e^{-nx}<1$?

Comment: @evinda because $e^{-nx}=1/e^{nx}$ and $e^{nx}$ is greater than 1 for $x\gt 0$

Comment: If $x > 0$ then $-x < 0$ and $e^{-x} < e^0 = 1$. The series in question becomes a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Ok,I understand!!!Thank you both!!! And something else..so,if $\sum {u_n}$ converges $u_n \to 0$..but if $u_n \to 0$,can we conclude that $\sum u_n$ converges?

Comment: @evinda No you can't make that conclusion. A standard counterexample is $\sum 1/n$.

Comment: So,I can just say that if $u_n \not\to  0$,the series $\sum u_n$ does not converge.But,if $u_n \to 0$,I cannot tell if the series converges or not...right??

Comment: @evinda Correct!

Comment: Nice,thank you very much!!!

Comment: @evinda Happy to help!